# how to change a imageButton and check the state

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I have a play/pause and a like/not liked button. I believe how it should work is that I check the state of the image button and whatever it is not when it is pressed it should change the image. the buttons also change actions based on the state of the button (play button stuff is paused , paused stuff is playing yada yada)

so currently I have

```
        // if the id of the song matches any of the 
        holder.likes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.likes.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_favorite);

            }
        });


    }
```

which works BUT I have no way to change it back. I have seen it mentioned here using

```
if ((int) image.getTag() == R.drawable.apicture) {
      // do your stuff
 }
```

but this hasn't worked for me ( I should mention that I set up the tags using .setTag(I think) and it didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

you can check which drawable is currently set in `ImageButton` using below code

```
if (ivPlayPauseButton.getDrawable().getConstantState() == ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.stop).getConstantState()) {
    //... stop playing
} else {
    //... start playing
}
```

Comment: ConctextCompat is part of a deprecated library, is there any other possible solution?

Comment: use androidx library and `ContextCompat` from androidx. see https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat